# Buttons with no background from missing css file

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

Buttons on the website are missing their style and that turns them invisible all thought they are still there but white and the customers can't see them.
The error is Mixed Content: The page at 'https://.com/mazhe/obleklo/dolnishta.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://.com/theme_options/css/index/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was not clear enough for me, but I think you can resolve it with add permissions in .htaccess file.